# Normalized $p(x)-\mathrm{laplacian}$ is uniformly elliptic?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

The normalized $p(x)-\mathrm{laplacian}$ is defined by

$$-\Delta_{p(x)}^{N} u = -\operatorname{tr}\Big( \big( I + \frac{(p(x)-2)}{|Du|^{2}}Du \otimes Du\big)D^{2}u\Big)=0 ,$$ from now on, two hypotheses are necessary the function $p$ is Lipschitz and $\inf p >1$. Under these conditions, can there be any hope that this operator will be uniformly elliptical? If the answer is negative, there is some condition on $ p $ so that this operator is uniformly elliptical in addition to imposing $p (x) = \mathrm{constant}$?

OBS: We work in a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: well, it depends on your definition of "uniformly elliptic" for nonlinear operators...